# Questions about items on Jepp charts…

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

1. On a Jeppesen IFR low enroute chart, there's occasionally a different altitude below/next to the MEA with a "T" next to it. (For example: V16 between GACEB and SHAKY, there's a "2900T" next to the 4500 MEA.) What is this "T" altitude?
2. Similar to the question above, but on a Jeppesen high enroute chart, there's occasionally a "D" below/next to a given altitude. (For example: Q20 between Fusco and JCT, there's 18000, with "24000D" below it.) What is this "D" altitude?
3. On a Jeppesen STAR, there are a combination of dashed and solid course lines. (For example: On KDFW's Sasie 6 Arrival, there are several dashed course lines prior to Sasie, after which the course is marked by a solid line.) What is the difference between the dashed and solid lines?

Thanks.

Comment: SASIE6 is not an arrival into DFW airport, though it does serve other airports in the DFW area.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have access to Jepp charts, but I do have access to SkyVector and [this March 2012 Jepp legend](https://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf).

> **1.** On a Jeppesen IFR low enroute chart, there's occasionally a different altitude below/next to the MEA with a "T" next to it. (For example: V16 between GACEB and SHAKY, there's a "2900T" next to the 4500 MEA.) What is this "T" altitude?

From page ENROUTE-6 on the Jepp legend:
[image: Section of the Jeppesen Enroute Chart legend displaying airway designators and segment altitude information]

> **35—** Minimum Obstruction Clearance Altitude (MOCA).

This corresponds with the Government chart which has, on V16 between GACEB and SHAKY, the MEA `4500` above the MOCA `*2900`.
[image: Section of the FAA Low Enroute Chart legend showing the symbology for a Minimum Obstruction Clearance Altitude, consisting of the the altitude in hundreds of feet preceded by the asterisk symbol]

---

> **2.** Similar to the question above, but on a Jeppesen high enroute chart, there's occasionally a "D" below/next to a given altitude. (For example: Q20 between FUSCO and JCT, there's 18000, with "24000D" below it.) What is this "D" altitude?

The 2012 Jepp legend does not list what a "D" suffix means on an altitude, but it does say (referring to the above screengrab)

> **34—** GPS MEA.

We can compare to the Government legend:
[image: Section of the FAA High Enroute Chart legend showing the symbology for Minimum Enroute Altitude, Maximum Authorized Altitude, MEA for GNSS-RNAV aircraft, and MEA for DME/DME/IRU-RNAV aircraft]
and we can say with confidence that the "D" suffix lists the MEA for a DME/DME/IRU-equipped aircraft, just as "G" indicates the MEA for a GPS-equipped aircraft.

---

> **3.** On a Jeppesen STAR, there are a combination of dashed and solid course lines. (For example: On KDFW's Sasie 6 Arrival, there are several dashed course lines prior to Sasie, after which the course is marked by a solid line.) What is the difference between the dashed and solid lines?

From page SID/STAR-4 of the Jepp legend, a thick solid line represents a "common course used by multiple transitions" while a thick dashed line represents a "transition track." This is analogous to the thick black line for common routes and thin black line for transition routes on Government charts.